# Credit Based Shopping on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce, credits

I'm trying to build a website that has items for sale by credits only.  The credits would be entered for all users by an admin only (manually).  And the items could be shopped on the site by users who would see something they want, they'd be able to see how many 'credits' they have accrued, and then build a cart and place an order by spending these credits.  There would be absolutely no need for actual money, no shipping, just a notification sent to the admins that an order has been requested, who and what that order request is, and the 'credits' deducted from their account.

Can anybody point in the direction of the right direction to build something like this?  I'm thinking Wordpress because I'm familiar with the dashboard and backend of it, but I'm not opposed to another CMS tool if there's a better one for this idea.

Comment: no shipping. So is it a pick up only? what happens after the shopping is done? Is the product just online or real thing?

Comment: You are correct, no shipping, and pickup only.  The products are physical objects, and we have somebody in house who manages stock.  This is going to be part of an employee reward program.  So only our employees will be using it (no guest access, users must log in via accounts we create for them).  After they're done shopping and they exchange points for the products, their 'points' would be deducted, and an admin notified so we know to take them their selected product.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe WordPress has anything out of the box like this, but you can always search for a plugin that does what you are describing.

If there isn't one, you may consider installing WooCommerce and creating "coupons" instead. But I don't know if that would work for what you are talking about or not.